# Eclipse Timestamp compiletime Android

Tags: android, eclipse, date, time, compile-time

I am using Eclipse for Android SDK on Linux, and searching for a way to add the date and starttime of the compilation to one of the xml files. I like to see on the device which *build version* I am using, without updating this information before every compile step manually.

So far by searching the net I only found hints like "use ant".

I guess I have to use /proc/driver/rtc which is a dynamic "file" provided by the linux kernel that contains real time updated lines with colon separated text named for example "rtc_date" and "rtc_time". Including it and use the app on the device to get the information extracted.

Is there a better way? Like having eclipse either by knowing the time or stripping the information from *proc* and putting it at compile time in the xml file?

Its my first time using eclipse, so please excuse if I asked something obvious or impossible.

Regards 
ct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this code to get application build time. I know this is not outputting to an XML, but if you are trying to get when the app was build, this should work.

```
private long getAppBuildTime() {
    if(cachedAppBuildTime == null) {
        try{
            ApplicationInfo ai = appContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(appContext.getPackageName(), 0);
            ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(ai.sourceDir);
            ZipEntry ze = zf.getEntry("classes.dex");
            cachedAppBuildTime = ze.getTime();
            log("app build time " + cachedAppBuildTime);
        }catch(Throwable t){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return cachedAppBuildTime;
}
```

The `appContext` variable in the code is obtained via `context.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I modified it a bit and works exactly like I hoped for.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same strategy as yigit except I prefer the MANIFEST.MF file.
This one is regenerated even if a layout is modified (which is not the case for classes.dex).

It result in the following code:

```
private long mAppBuildTime = -1;

public long getAppBuildTime() {
  if (mAppBuildTime == -1) {
    try{
      ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
      ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(ai.sourceDir);
      ZipEntry ze = zf.getEntry("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
      mAppBuildTime = ze.getTime();
      zf.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
  }
  return mAppBuildTime;
}
```